# UK visa hotel booking and contact information

Tags: visas, uk, hotels

It seems like that this question has been asked for visas to other countries, but I am not sure if it applies juts the same for a UK short-term visit visa.

I want to visit UK for 2 weeks and the visa asks for the "details of where you’ll be staying during your visit".

In the application, I need to provide the address and phone number of where I'll be staying. Is the normal approach to this (assuming I plan on staying in hotels or hostels and have no family members there) to just book a refundable hotel reservation?

Also, if I plan on visiting several different cities in UK (ie. London, Manchester, Edinburgh), should I just put the first place I am staying at on the application?
I can then attach an itinerary of the trip with the address and phone number of a hotel booked in each city for the duration I am there.

Answer (score 7):

**I plan on staying in hotels or hostels and have no family members there) to just book a refundable hotel reservation?**

UK != Schengen. The UK does not want to see bookings and if you include them, it amounts to an admission that you have not read the guidance.  Examine this screen cap...

[image]

Source: [Visitor Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf)

If you feel uncomfortable about omitting reservations and bookings, you can always include a statement in the 'remarks' section of the application along the lines of...

> Following your guidance, I am not including flight and hotel
>   reservations until specifically requested.  I am happy to make a
>   personal appearance at the British Consulate to show these once the
>   visa has been issued.

**Also, if I plan on visiting several different cities in UK (ie. London, Manchester, Edinburgh), should I just put the first place I am staying at on the application?**

If you are visiting multiple locales, include a proposed itinerary. If you are staying with private hosts as in a family visitor, include their address. Otherwise include an indicative entry for each location.

Note: "hotel bookings" include hostel, AirBnB, or any similar accommodation arrangement.